# Create .lib file with c++ and Fortran / Call c++ code from Fortran / Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, fortran, object-files, psse

I am attempting to create a .lib library file that contains Fortran functions that call c++ functions, but I am getting the dreaded "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol...".  The code will eventually be compiled with a bunch of other libraries as a DLL and used in a separate program (PSSE).  I am getting the compile error when PSSE attemps to create the DLL using my library.  Here is the code I attempting to use, followed by the compiling code.  The code should just add two numbers together and output the answer.

fort_code.f

```
  SUBROUTINE TESTCPP ( II, JJ, KK, LL )
  INCLUDE 'COMON4.INS'

  integer*4, external :: CPPFUNCTION

  INTEGER a, b, c, test

  IF (.NOT. IFLAG) RETURN

  a = ICON(II)
  b = ICON(II + 1)
  test = CPPFUNCTION( a , b, c )
  WRITE ( ITERM, * ) 'C = ', c
  RETURN
  END
```

cpp_code.cpp

```
extern "C" {
      void _CPPFUNCTION(int a, int b, int *c);
}

void _CPPFUNCTION(int a, int b, int *c) {
      *c = a + b;
    }
```

compile.bat

```
cl /nologo /MD /c /W3 /O2 /FD /EHsc /errorReport:prompt /D"MSWINDOWS" /D"WIN32" ^
   /D"_WINDOWS" /D"NDEBUG" "cpp_code.cpp"

IFORT /nologo /Od /Oy- /assume:buffered_io /traceback /libs:dll /threads /c /Qip ^
      /extend_source:132 /noaltparam /fpscomp:logicals /warn:nodeclarations ^
      /warn:unused /warn:truncated_source /Qauto /Op /iface:cvf /define:DLLI ^
      /include:"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE32\PSSLIB" ^
      /object:"fort_code.OBJ" ^
      "fort_code.f" 

lib /out:fort_cpp.lib fort_code.obj cpp_code.obj
```

When the PSSE program attempts to create the DLL, this is the output I get:

```
 ifort /nologo /assume:buffered_io /traceback /libs:dll /threads /c /Qip /extend_source:132 /noaltparam /fpscomp:logicals /Qprec /warn:declarations /warn:unused /warn:truncated_source /Qauto /fp:source /iface:cvf /define:DLLI /include:"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE32\PSSLIB" /object:"C:\temp\INIT_620289\11hw2ap_conec.obj" /module:"C:\temp\INIT_620289" "11hw2ap_conec.f"


 ifort /nologo /assume:buffered_io /traceback /libs:dll /threads /c /Qip /extend_source:132 /noaltparam /fpscomp:logicals /Qprec /warn:declarations /warn:unused /warn:truncated_source /Qauto /fp:source /iface:cvf /define:DLLI /include:"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE32\PSSLIB" /object:"C:\temp\INIT_620289\11hw2ap_conet.obj" /module:"C:\temp\INIT_620289" "11hw2ap_conet.f"


 link /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT @"C:\temp\INIT_620289\linkfilestod9p1.txt" /OUT:"C:\temp\INIT_620289\11hw2ap_dsusr.dll" /map:"C:\temp\INIT_620289\11hw2ap_dsusr.map"

 fort_cpp.lib(fort_code.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CPPFUNCTION@12 referenced in function _TESTCPP
 C:\temp\INIT_620289\11hw2ap_dsusr.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

 ERROR during link(1)... Aborted
```

conec/conet are simply Fortran calls to the external library functions:

```
      SUBROUTINE CONEC
C
      INCLUDE 'COMON4.INS'
C
      CALL TESTCPP         ( 55791,     0,     0,     0)
C
      RETURN
      END
      SUBROUTINE CONET
C
      INCLUDE 'COMON4.INS'
C
      IF (.NOT. IFLAG) GO TO 9000
C
C  NETWORK MONITORING MODELS
C
C
 9000 CONTINUE
C
      RETURN
      END
```

I have seen a few different examples of calling c++ functions from Fortran, but they all look slightly different.  One thing I noticed was differening uses of the `_` before or after the c++ function name.  How do I know which to use: `_CPPFUNCTION`, `CPPFUNCTION`, or `CPPFUNCTION_`.  Do I need to export the function in c++ using `__declspec( dllexport )`?  Do I need to create an `ALIAS:'_CPPFUNCTION'` in the Fortran code?

I am using the following compilers:
ifort: IVF IA-32 v12.1.0.233
cl: v16.00.30319.01 x86

Is there something I am missing to link the c++ code properly to the Fortran functions?

Comment: Seems like you should specify calling conventions. cdecl or stdcall, I don't know, I program only for Unix. The best way is to use Fortran 2003 interoperability with C (and `iso_c_binding module`).

Comment: I see how this is being done with a main program, but I am having a tough time getting this to work with a subroutine.

Comment: Recently I did some dll to a Win32 game in Fortran and it "just worked" flawlesly, when I used Fortran 2003 and `iso_c_binding`, but your mileage can vary. I cannot say anything about specifying the conventions manually.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with is that there are a lot of options. None, one or two underscores before and or after, string length after a variable or at the end of a list, call by value or call by reference. Capitalize, lowercase or original naming. With just these options, the probability of getting it right is already lower than 1 in 100 (1/3*1/3*1/2*1/2*1/3).

You can reduce it a bit by introspecting the .lib file using the [dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) utility and manually checking intel fortran default settings and the settings in the project files.

The most elegant way, like some suggested, is to use the combination of `bind(C)` and [iso_c_binding](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/generating+c+interfaces) module. The `bind(C)` statement avoids having to know the name mangling. The `iso_c_bindings` provides [c strings](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/generating+c+interfaces#strings) and `integer(c_int)` instead of `integer*4` to ensure compatibility of your types with C. You have to know that fortran calls by reference by default and  you can use `, value` to call by value. This should raise your succes rate all the way back to 1.

Here is a simple example of how to call the add1 function defined in c++ below:

**test.f90**

```
  program example

    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    interface
       integer(c_int) function add1(x) bind(C,name="add1")
         !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: add1
         use iso_c_binding
         integer(c_int), value :: x
       end function add1
    end interface

    call callingadd1()
  contains
    subroutine callingadd1()
      write(*,*) '1+1=', add1(1)
    end subroutine callingadd1
  end program example
```

**add1.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
  int add1(int x);
}

int add1(int x) {
  return(x+1);
}
```

*edit* an example with only a subroutine. For inclusion in your shared object/dll/dylib.

**subroutineonly.f90**

```
subroutine callingadd1() bind(C, name="callingadd1")
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: callingadd1
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  interface
     integer(c_int) function add1(x) bind(C,name="add1")
       !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: add1
       use iso_c_binding
       integer(c_int), value :: x
     end function add1
  end interface
  write(*,*) '1+1=', add1(1)
end subroutine callingadd1
```

Comment: Can the `iso_c_binding` be done from within a `SUBROUTINE` as opposed to putting it in a `PROGRAM` as you suggested?

Comment: I updated the example to use a subroutine. You can also put both the interface and the subroutine in a module, or you can put the interface inside the subroutine.

Comment: A terminology quibble that's commonly seen in Fortran answers on this site - the intrinsic module ISO_C_BINDING is part of C interoperability, but it isn't the part that's relevant to the OP's issue.  It's the BIND attribute that he needs - if you took the USE statement out of your example the compiler would still get the name mangling right.  Using "iso_c_binding" as a synonym for C interoperability is inaccurate and can potentially confuse newcomers.

Comment: I guess my question is it possible to use it in a subroutine module by itself.  This will eventually be a library that will be used by a program that I have no control over.  So what I am wondering is if the `use iso_c_binding` and `implicit none` needs to be defined in the program level, or if it can be laid out inside the subroutine.

Comment: See extra example. If you compile this into your dll, the function should be callable.